# Reading source code of QGIS tool?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I can see the source code of the core QGIS plugins from the repository in github. I want to use the code snippets of "information about object" tool of QGIS. I tried searching in program files but I'm having trouble finding the code. Someone could help?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the [Identify tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify), the [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgsmaptoolidentify.cpp)  is on GitHub.